# PhoneJS - launching Demos

Tags: android, phonejs

I have one simple question conserning PhoneJS http://phonejs.devexpress.com/Documentation
and it's demos - how to launch and preview them on Android devise?

I've loaded a package and tried to run demos through Eclipse, using

```
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android/html/index.html");
```

But only black screen is visible.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I also not found this PhoneJS information in documentation. I wrote to support and they told me PhoneJS application is like any PhoneGap based application can be packaged with PhoneGap and in http://build.phonegap.com site.

PhoneGap Build worked well, but it is little slow.

Do you see any errors or simple black screen?

Answer (score 0):

Possible files, mentioned in the index.html file, are spelled in the different case from files on the disk, e.g. you have line

```
script type="text/javascript" src="data/db.js"
```

but on the disk there is "Data" (not "data") folder or "Db.js" (not "db.js") file.

It makes sense then application is uploaded on android device. You should ensure file names spelling.

Thanks, Serge

Comment: I cheked folders on my disk and HTML file, everything seems to be ok. But the black screen is still the only thing I see.

Comment: It looks like your problem is very similar one is discussed in the http://www.devexpress.dev/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q432054 thread. Can you share your project here or submit a ticket on the support.devexpress.com site?